# How to add an empty span to Simple Form wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I would like to build a custom wrapper for my input fields using SimpleForm that has an empty span element beneath the label.

I would like the HTML to end up like this:

```
<div class="custom-input">
  <input />
  <label />
  <span class="bar"/>
</div>
```

my `initializers/simple_form.rb` includes this:

```
config.wrappers :custom_input, tag: 'div', class: "custom-input" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.wrapper tag: 'span', class: 'bar' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :label
    end
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
end
```

This wraps the input and label in a span, but I would like the span to be below the label.

I have tried building a custom simple form component without any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is not something that you can handle by using CSS instead? Whats the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I can add the span in HTML, but I'd like to DRY up those files if I can. (I'd like this format for all input fields)

Comment: Fair question, you can achieve a lot of cool custom checkbox styling by styling the span below the checkbox input, so yes it would be nice to know if this is possible and how to do it.